# Remove accents from a text file

Tags: c#, user-interface, diacritics

I have issues with removing accents from a text file program replaces characters with diacritics to ? Here is my code:

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                byte[] tmp;
                tmp = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text);
                richTextBox2.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp);


            }

        }
```

Comment: small example please "of removing accents"

Comment: input včľťšľžšžščýščýťčáčáčťáčáťýčťž -> vcltslzszsc�sc�tc�c�ct�c�t�ctz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.Text = "včľťšľžšžščýščýťčáčáčťáčáťýčťž";            

string text1 = richTextBox1.Text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

string pattern = @"\p{M}";
string text2 = Regex.Replace(text1, pattern, "�");

richTextBox2.Text = text2;
```

First [normalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the string.
Then with a regular expression replace all diacritics. Pattern `\p{M}` is [Unicode Category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) - All diacritic marks.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/3047078

```
static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
  var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
  var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (var c in normalizedString)
  {
    var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
    if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
    {
      stringBuilder.Append(c);
    }
  }

  return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

usage:

```
string result = RemoveDiacritics("včľťšľžšžščýščýťčáčáčťáčáťýčťž");
```

results in `vcltslzszscyscytcacactacatyctz`