# c# replace ՛ characters

Tags: c#, replace, unicode, special-characters

Why I can't replace ARMENIAN EMPHASIS MARK with an empty string?

```
Replace("՛", String.Empty)
```

Where **՛** is unocode char U+055B  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=055b

Comment: Sure you can replace it.
Show us what makes you ***think*** you cannot replace it.
Don't tell us, show us.
In code.

Comment: Seems to work ok. https://ideone.com/OzG1d0 Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I think we need to normalize the string first. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37070303/5045688

Answer (score 1):

Its method with return.

Assign result.

```cs
var names = new List<String>
{
    "Ana՛",
    "Felipe՛",
    "Emillia՛"
};

foreach (var name in names)
{
    var newName = name.Replace("՛",string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {newName}");
}
```